# Подключение HTML файла в PHP

Tags: php, html

Доброго времени суток !

Вопрос: Если Я с помощью функции `readfile` подключу `html` файл в котором будет отрезок `html` кода без подключенного `css` стиля, сможет ли этот файл прочесть стили из файла откуда он подключается ?
Пример кода:

Основной `PHP` файл:

```
<head>
     <title>Тайтл</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
     <?php if(условие)): ?>
     <?php readfile('present.htm'); ?>
     <?php else: ?>
     /*
          тут код
     */
     <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

Вот код `html` файла:

```
<div class="Body">  
    <!-- Тут HTML код -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключенные стили будут применены к коду вставленному из файла. Но разве это сложно протестировать?

Comment: Стили еще не написаны, а реализация уже в голову пришла.